# How to prove that there are $O(T\ln T)$ zeros in the critical strip of the Riemann zeta function?

Tags: asymptotics, roots, riemann-zeta

Define $F(T)$ as the number of solutions to $\zeta(a+ ti) =0$ for $0\le t\le T$ and $0<a<1$.

How to show that $F(T)= O(T\ln T)$?

For clarity, $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function, $i$ is the imaginary unit and $O$ is big-O notation.

Comment: Perhaps you would be interested in a book, Edwards "Riemann Zeta Function" which discusses this and many interesting aspects of the RZF.

Comment: @anon sorry I was sloppy.

Comment: @Andrew I do not have access to books.

Comment: Anyway, here is a link to a nice answer about zeros (containing a further link) both of which may be of interest to you http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442390/riemann-zeta-function-number-of-zeros/442686#442686

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the link. ALthough Im not so familiar with the Z-function and those techniques.
However that link is about the critical line alone. Whereas I am asking about the critical strip. If I got it right that is.
I know there must be results about the strip too , because it is required for the PNT and other related stuff. Although it is known that more than 60 % is on the critical line ( I believe 60 % is the best known today , Hardy proved 40 % I think ) that does not seem sufficient for the error term in the PNT. See the explicit formula.

Comment: @Mike thanks for the edit. Looks nice now.