# Is this plot of the argument of the Riemann zeta function around ZetaZero(127) correct?

Tags: riemann-zeta

```
(*Mathematica 8 start*)
Clear[n, k, t, z, FL, NZ]
N[ZetaZero[127]]
NZ[t_] = Arg[Zeta[1/2 + I*t]]/Pi;
Plot[NZ[t], {t, 280, 284}]
Plot[NZ[t], {t, 282.3, 282.6}]
```

Look at these two graphs of $$\arg(\zeta(1/2+I\cdot t))$$ around the Riemann zeta function zero 0.5 + 282.465 I:

[image: Failure zoom out]

[image: Failure zoom in]

Is it correct that close to $t=282.465$ the graph should make a jump increase of size $2$, and then should continue only slightly downwards, and then should suddenly decrease a step of almost equal to $1$? Should it be that way?

Comment: Your question here is related to my recent question at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4037391. By the way, what would be the advantage of the zeta zero counting function that you were attempting to derive (which last I recall you could only evaluate using NIntegrate) over  formulas such as $N_0(T)=1+\frac{\vartheta(T)}{\pi}+\frac{\arg\left(\zeta\left(\frac12+i\,T\right)\right)}{\pi}$? Would your formula not exhibit the same anomalies as this formula near Gram points that violate Gram's law?

Comment: I seem to recall now you were working on a formula for calculating the location of the zeta zeros, so perhaps my question in the previous comment was misguided and I should really be asking if violations of Gram's law causes problems with your algorithm when attempting to find the location of a zeta zero in the neighborhood of a Gram point where Gram's law is violated..

Comment: It might not be feasible but if you could make an integrable approximation of the zeta zero counting function it would give a formula for the zeta zeros. More exceptions like this  one here (in my question) are found here: https://oeis.org/A153815   Notice also that any solution to the integral of Log[Zeta[s]] (in the critical strip) would be interesting with regards to the Riemann hypothesis as pointed out here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/57944/25104

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument jumps by $\pi$ at each zero because the curve $\zeta(\frac12+it)$ passes right through the origin. (With the principal argument the jump will be upwards or downwards according to whether the curve passes from the lower half-plane to the upper one, or vice versa).

The large jump by $2\pi$ just before the zero is just caused by normalization of the argument to fall within the standard interval $(-\pi,\pi]$. It shows that the curve crosses the negative real axis shortly before the zero at 282.465.

---

Note that the almost stable downwards slope of the graph *between* the jumps is because what you're really plotting is minus the the [Riemann-Siegel theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_theta_function), plus $\pi$ times the number of critical zeroes below $t$, modulo $2\pi$, and the theta function is quite smooth for such large $t$.

Comment: What about the sudden downward fall of $1/2$ is that as it should be too?

Comment: @MatsGranvik: I don't see any jumps of size $1/2$ -- only ones of size $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Well it is not exactly $1/2$ but only close to $1/2$.

Comment: @MatsGranvik: I don't even see any jump close to 1/2. The graph jumps from near $-1$ to near $1$, a distance of $2$, and then from near $1$ to near $0$, a distance of $1$. Are you misunderstanding the vertical scale on the graph you show?

Comment: But all in all you are saying that the plots are as they should be and that they are correct?

Comment: Yes I misunderstood the scale in the vertical direction because I was thinking in terms of $\pi$

Comment: @MatsGranvik: I can't vouch for the _correctness_, but it doesn't look _wrong_ to me.