# Numerical values for $e^{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning

Is it a coincidence that $\Re\  e^{\frac{1}{2} +i\rho_1}$ and $\ \zeta^{\frac{1}{2} +i\rho_1}$ are so close in value?

[image]

From *Mathematica* I am getting $e^{\frac{1}{2} +i\rho_1} \approx 1.05148\times10^{-6}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you by $\rho_1$ mean the imaginary part of the first non-trivial zero of $\zeta(s)$ and that you by $\zeta^{\frac12+i\rho_1}$ mean $\zeta\left(\frac12+i\rho_1\right)$, which obviously equals $0$ if my first assumption is correct.

Your question can then be rephrased as *"Is it a coincidence that $\Re\;e^{\frac12+i\rho_1}$ is very close to $0$?"*

First note that $e^{\frac12+i\rho_1} = e^{\frac12}\left(\cos \rho_1 + i\sin \rho_1\right)$ and thus $\Re\; e^{\frac12+i\rho_1} = \sqrt{e}\cos\rho_1$.

Since $\cos x = 0$ is true for $x = \left(n + \frac12\right)\pi, \;n \in \Bbb{Z}$, your observation is true if $\rho_1$ is in some sense close to $\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi$. And indeed, $\frac{\rho_1}{\pi} \approx 4.49922$. Your question can therefore again be rephrased to:

*"Is it a coincidence that $\rho_1$ is close to $4.5\pi$?"*

I believe the answer to this is yes.

A related question, which includes your observation and more discussions about how $\rho_1$ can be approximated, can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190080/what-is-the-formula-for-the-first-riemann-zeta-zero).

Comment: Many thanks for your reply & taking me through the stages of the argument. I have had a look at the link you have posted & will look at it in further depth later. - Again, many thanks.

Comment: @martin No problem, glad to be of help!