# Can we prove $B (n) = \frac{1}{4} G (n - 1) G (n)$ is an indicator function that takes on the value 1 for 'bad' and 0 for "good" Gram points?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, lambert-w

Let
\begin{equation}
  g (n) = 2 \pi e^{1 + W \left( \frac{8 n + 1}{8 e} \right)}
\end{equation}
be the approximate value of the $n$-th Gram point.

Let
  \begin{equation}
    G (n) = \frac{Z (g (n))}{| Z (g (n)) |} + \frac{Z (g (n + 1))}{| Z (g (n +
    1)) |}
  \end{equation}
 where Z is the Hardy Z function then the function defined by
  \begin{equation}
    B (n) = \frac{1}{4} G (n - 1) G (n)
  \end{equation}
  takes on the value $1$ when $n$ is a `bad` Gram point for which $(- 1)^{n
  + 1} Z (g (n)) > 0$ and the value $0$ when it is a `good` Gram point $(-
  1)^{n + 1} Z (g (n)) < 0$.

Comment: what's Z?.......

Comment: @mathworker21 the Hardy Z function . updated

Comment: The exact expression for the Gram points is the inverse function of RiemannSiegelTheta, as I was told by reuns. In mathematica that would be computed as: Table[N[InverseFunction[RiemannSiegelTheta][Pi*(n - 1)], 30], {n, 0, 12}]

Comment: Yes, it's not needed here tho, the approx inverse gives you the same answer

Comment: One word of caution though. Take for example this sequence: https://oeis.org/A282896  "Indices n such that sign(Im(zetazero(n)) - 2*Pi*e*exp(LambertW((n - 11/8)/e))) = 1." At first there appears to be different ways to compute the same sequence, but at "n = 28813, 30264, 36720, 45925,..."  the pattern starts to fail. So I am wondering how far have you computed Gram points with the criteria above? Does it hold past say 28813?

Comment: I have not tried that far, good point

Comment: I'm pretty sure the lambertW approximation gets more accurate as n increases , so in that case the exact gram points via numerical inversion isn't necessary

Comment: you were right @MatsGranvik  the pattern breaks down as n increases.. many false postives

Comment: @crow I asked a different question about Gram points on Mathoverflow and got the following answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/259604/25104 that ends with: "So instead of looking at the first $10^6$ zeros, you might look at some interval much further out." So apparently also a false positive but much higher up on the number line than I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula fails around n=20,000 or so

Answer (score 0):

The formula first fails at $n = 378$ (a good Gram point surrounded by bad Gram points), which the formula mispredicts as a bad Gram point.